# Creating Replaceable models

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I wanted to know if Modelica allows us to create replaceable models?

I was trying to redeclare the Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant to a block which goves constant voltage. I only need to change the unit of the variable k. (from nothing to "Volts").
Is it possible to do this in openmodelica?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need replaceable model for that.
Just use a modifier on the Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant component:

```
Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant const(k(unit = "V"));
```

But to answer your question, yes OpenModelica supports replaceable models.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Can you please provide me a small example as to how i can create a replaceable model and redeclare it? I couldnt find any info online

Comment: I tried creating a model for the above question.

class Constant "Generate constant signal of type Real"
  replaceable parameter Real k(start = 1);
  extends VisualModelica.Models.SignalBlocks.Interfaces.SO;
equation
  y = k;
end Constant

model ConstantVoltage
  import SI = Modelica.SIunits;
  extends Constant(redeclare parameter SI.Voltage k(start = 1) "constant Voltage");
end ConstantVoltage;

Now when I drag and drop this and double click, the GUI does not show the unit(V) or the comment(Constant Voltage). But when I instantiate it, the redeclaration chages are reflected in it. Why so?

Comment: You need to add graphical annotations to your model.

Comment: The graphical comments are there. I couldnt post the entire thing in a comment. So I removed it. Basically the constant class is a copy of the code of Blocks.Sources.Constant

Answer (score 1):

The topic of `replaceable` components is discussed in [the chapter on architectures](http://book.xogeny.com/components/architectures/) in my online book, "[Modelica by Example](http://book.xogeny.com/)".  You might find it useful.